# Transient power spectrum of a damped, driven simple harmonic oscillator (DDSHO)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, dissipation

Our prof in the class mentioned something called the transient power spectrum of a damped, driven simple harmonic oscillator (DDSHO). Assuming that we're given the drive frequency, and we're to find the damping constant and the natural frequency of the system experimentally, we look at a quantity $I(\omega_{obs} , \tau)$ where $\tau$ is the time of making the observation. We should therefore get a 3D plot with $I$ on the $z$-axis, frequency on the $x$-axis, and time on the $y$-axis, so that in the limit that $\tau$ approaches infinity, there will be only one peak corresponding the steady state solution.

Now I want to find the exact mathematical form of $I$. I know that the regular fourier transform won't work, since we'd be integrating over time, and even though we'd get a quantity that depends only on $\omega$, we wouldn't be able to tell which $\omega$ corresponds to natural frequency/ frequency corresponding to the transient solution, since we don't have the time evolution of $I$.

I was thinking something along the lines of $I(\omega, \tau) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) x(\tau - t) e^{-i\omega t}dt$, but I do not know how to make any physical sense out of it. Any help would be appreciated!